# Force exact match for filters in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, filter

I am trying to force exact match results for the filters in my laravel crm, which uses Vue.js for front end. currently what happens is that if I filter with sales person ID that is '6' it also shows sales persons with ID's "60's" and "600's", but I want it to exact match the filter results.

Here's the code snippet of the Vue.js:

```
pushFieldValue: function(key, { target }, indexKey, indexType = '', condition = 'in') {
            let targetValue = target.value.trim();

            this.addField[indexKey] = false;

            let values = (this.columns || this.tableData.columns)[key].values || [];

            if (values.indexOf(targetValue) == -1) {
                if (indexType == "single_dropdown" && values.length) {
                    values = [];
                }

                values.push(targetValue);

                this.updateFilterValues({
                    key: indexKey,
                    values,
                    condition
                });

                target.value = '';
            }

            this.$forceUpdate();
        },
```

I tried updating the code, to the following but it still won't work:

```
pushFieldValue: function(key, { target }, indexKey, indexType = '', condition = 'in') {
    let targetValue = target.value.trim();

    this.addField[indexKey] = false;

    let values = (this.columns || this.tableData.columns)[key].values || [];

    let exactMatchFound = false;
    let selectedOption = null;
    for (const option of (this.columns || this.tableData.columns)[key].dropdown_options) {
        if (option.label === targetValue) {
            exactMatchFound = true;
            selectedOption = option;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exactMatchFound) {
        target.value = '';
        return; // No exact match found, do not proceed with filtering
    }

    if (indexType === "single_dropdown" && values.length) {
        values = [];
    }

    values.push(selectedOption.value);

    this.updateFilterValues({
        key: indexKey,
        values,
        condition
    });

    target.value = '';

    this.$forceUpdate();
},
```

Comment: It's hard for others to debug filtering not having any idea what the actual data is being filtered.  Give some examples of what `values` contains and what kind of values `targetValue` might be, and explain how `targetValue` is meant to filter `values`.  Your first code block is just looking for an exact object that matches `targetValue`, while the second is specifically filtering based on a `label` property, meaning the code blocks are contradictory.  Provide some example data and please elaborate how exactly the filtering should work.